# python3 manage.py makemigrations No changes detected

Tags: django, python-3.x, makemigrations

(fcdjango_venv) Subinui-MacBook-Pro:Impassion_community subin$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

I'm learning Basic Django right now, and was following the lecture, but got problem. 
I followed the lecture, so first I typed the code on models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Impassionuser(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=64, 
                                verbose_name='사용자명')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64, 
                                verbose_name='비밀번호')
    registered_dttm = models.DataTimeField(auto_now_add=True, 
                                verbose_name='등록시간')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Impassion_Impassionuser'
```

and then on Terminal, I typed

```
(fcdjango_venv) Subinui-MacBook-Pro:Impassion_community subin$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

but the result was

```
No changes detected
```

In the lecture, after typing python3 manage.py makemigrations

it shows

```
Migrations for "User" :
    user/migrations/0001_initial.py
        - Create model User
```

how can I get the same result?

Comment: Did you put your app `user` on `INSTALLED_APPS` (settings.py)?

Comment: Make sure you have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`

Comment: I already added user on INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Show your project folder structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django custom user model in admin, relation "auth\_user" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953302/django-custom-user-model-in-admin-relation-auth-user-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Include the name of your app after the `makemigrations` command and make sure you have a `migrations` folder created within your app.

Comment: I have migrations folder in my app. and I included the name of my app after the makemigations, and I got other mssg this time. "No installed app with label 'USER'.' but I've already added the app on INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py)

Comment: Make sure `user` is all lowercase.  Please post your `settings.py`.